# Prevent bad rankings on a Q and A site for questions without an answer by using noindex until answered

Tags: seo, google-search, noindex

I have a website on which users can ask a question and also answer it. So, when a user asks a question, it creates a new webpage on website and below that question lies its answers.

I don't want search engines to index those pages or questions which don't have an answer, so I added an `if` condition stating if the question doesn't have answer show the `noindex` meta tag, if it does, then don't show it.

I was wondering if it is the right way to do so?

I mean, first when the question is asked and Google will crawl it, it will see the `noindex` tag. But after some time when it will have an answer, Google will see that it can be indexed.

Will it affect the ranking and overall performance in Google search results?

Comment: Why don’t you want answer-less pages to get indexed?

Comment: @unor Sir, because that would be of no use & will deliver no value to the users. So, google will probably never index high those pages.

Comment: @unor & I think that will be a bad sign for website. I only want google to index quality webpages :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bad logic, because all questions just after publishing don't have answers. Only with time they could be answered. If you want, that your unanswered Qs should be found through Google, than it is a bad logic to noindex them befor they get any answer.

I would establish a kind of time gap and engaging metric, like:

- a Q is indexed just after publishing, having no answers,
- if after some time (hours/days/weeks) it doesn't get an answer and/or generates only few clicks - than noindex it